# the elements move forward in the column

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a right column to implement and I choose to fix this column with css `position:relative` in order to put my different elements in `position:absolute` inside like this:

```
<!-- right Column   -->
<div class="col-xs-3 pl18"  style="position:relative;">

    <!-- Sans assurance -->
    <div class="row pt23 p-absolute t141"  >        
        #parse('/right-col/sans-assurance.html.vtl')
    </div><!-- end row alc mb30 -->

    <!--Tout savoir sur l'assurance Ad-valorem -->
    <div class="row  col-xs-12 info pt10 pb8 mt-7 left p-absolute t240"   >
        <p class="ml40">
            <a href="#" class="noir popup-faq" rel="38">Tout savoir sur l'assurance Ad-valorem</a>
        </p>
    </div><!--end row col-xs-12 info=(image en background)-->

    <!--    Tout savoir sur le contre-remboursement -->

    ## we display the I information when the option 335 (collect_on_delivery) is activated for the company
    #if($offre.getOption(335))
    <div class="row mb30 col-xs-12 info pt10 pb8 left mt-7"  id="collect_on_delivery" >   ##cache  style="height:50px;"                 
        <p class="ml40">
            <a href="#" class="noir popup-faq" rel="28">Tout savoir sur le contre-remboursement </a>
        </p>                                            
    </div><!--end row col-xs-12 info=(image en background)-->
    #end

    <!-- adresse-boite-postale -->
    <div class="row  pt23  p-absolute" style="top:842px;" id="adresse-boite-postale">                
        #parse('/right-col/adresse-boite-postale.html.vtl')
    </div><!-- end row alc mb30 -->

    <!-- telephone-bulle -->
    <div class="row pt23 " style="top:500px;">
        #parse('/right-col/telephone-bulle.html.vtl')
    </div><!-- end row alc mb30 -->

    <!-- informations-bordereaux -->
    <div class="row mb30 pt23 mt136 "  >                
        #parse('/right-col/informations-bordereaux.html.vtl')
    </div><!-- end row alc mb30 -->

    <!-- envoi reference interne -->
    <div class="row mb30 pt23 mt200"  >                         
        #parse('/right-col/envoi-reference-interne.html.vtl')
    </div><!-- end row alc mb30 -->

    <!-- Marchandises interdites -->
    <div class="row col-xs-12 info pt10 pb8 p-absolute left" style="top:1500px;">               
        <p class="ml40">
            <a href="#" class="noir popup-faq" rel="107">Marchandises interdites</a>
        </p>
    </div><!--end row col-xs-12 info=(image en background)-->

</div><!-- eod col-xs-3 -->
<!-- right Column   -->
```

But each time I add some new element in the head of my right column, the next elements move forward every time and I don’t like that, I try to do a code in jQuery but I haven’t got for the moment the good ideas. Please could you suggest me some ideas?

Thanks.

---

It's a little strange because I did a test with :

```
<body>
    <div>Hi</div>

    <div class="row" style="position: relative;">

        <div class="col-xs-3" style="position: absolute;top:10px;" >
                    Ola
                    <img src="fig-a01a.jpg" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3" style="position: absolute;top:200px;">
                    querida
                    <img src="Arthur.jpg" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;">
        </div>

         <div class="col-xs-1" style="position: absolute;top:400px;">
                    sin tchao
                    <img src="c.jpg" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;">
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-1" style="position: absolute;top: 20px;">
                    anh phuong
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-1" style="position: absolute;">
                    princessa
        </div>

     </div>
  </body>
```

and when I test there's no gap created between the different components and with my first block of code there is a gap created, I don't know why.

If anyone could me suggest me a thing...

Answer (score 0):

Wow... I find  a piece of solution, I will use in JQUERY :

```
 $("#id_of_the_component_HTML").css({left:X,top:Y});
```

To detect the existence of a component in a web page :

```
if($('#id_of_the_component_HTML').length>0){
```

So :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){

                if($('#bea').length>0){

                    $("#position").css({left:0,top:-60});

                }

            });

 </script>
```

with :

```
<div class=" col-xs-3 " id="bea" style="position: absolute;top:10px;" >
                    tao
                    <img src="bea.jpg" style="">
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-3" id="position" style="position: absolute;top:10px;" >
                    Ola
                    <img src="fig-p01a.jpg" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;">
        </div>
```

And I can move the object of ID position when I put the object of ID bea.

Ale.